# Controller not executing if changing constructor parameters

Tags: magento-2.1, construct

I have a Controller class as follow :

```
    class Delete extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


   protected $cache;
   protected $cacheManager;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cache,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager
)
   {
     parent::__construct($context);

     $this->cache = $cache;
     $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
 }


 public function execute()
 {

    $value = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

    $themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('thienphucvx_sample');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $themeTable WHERE post_id=$value";
    $connection->query($sql);

}
}
```

This controller is intended to delete a data from DB, what is strange is that when I simply add `cache` and `cacheManager` in the constructor, I have an ajax response from the controller but the delete is not processing. When I delete those 2 parameters from the constructor, all is well executing. What's going wrong with this constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the generation folder inside var and flush the cache

```
rm -rf generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy :

We should delete `generation/` directory when changing constructors parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.
That should help